# Google Drive API - Changing Owner of a file - Permissions error 400 "Permission type field required"

Tags: javascript, json, permissions, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) in Google Apps Script (which is sandboxed server-side Javascript that cannot use the Google Client API for Javascript).

I am a Google Apps super admin and authenticating as the user using Domain-wide delegation and a service account to impersonate users, and I can successfully make [Files:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) calls as other users within the domain.

Now I am trying to transfer ownership of a file from user A to user B, and making user C an editor by doing these steps:

1. When authenticated as user A, transfer ownership of the file from user A to user B by setting user B as an additional owner.
2. When authenticated as user A or B, make user C an editor of the file

I have already completed step 1 successfully.

For step 1, I assume the way to add user B as an owner, whether or not they are already shared on the file, is to use [Permissions:insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert). I have written this:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + fileId + '/permissions';

 var resource = {
  "type": "user",
  "role": "owner",
  "value": "userBEmail"
 };

 var requestBody = {};
 requestBody.method = 'POST';
 requestBody.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() };
 requestBody.contentType = 'application/json';
 requestBody.resource = JSON.stringify(resource);
 requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = true;

 try {

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);

   var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

   Logger.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));

 } catch(e) {

   Logger.log(e.message);

 }
```

The result is this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Permission type field required",
        "locationType": "other",
        "location": "permission.type"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Permission type field required"
  }
}
```

My questions:

1. Is this the proper way to accomplish transferring a file from one user to another?
2. Why is it saying `"Permission type field required"` if I have included that?
3. After I get step 1 working, is there a way to add the Step 2 into the same API call (for performance reasons because I plan to run this in a loop through up to 1,000 files)

Also worth mentioning: I was able to successfully transfer ownership of a file using the API explorer at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) from my account to another account. I provided the exact same file ID and content of the Request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

I used [UrlFetchApp.getRequest()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getRequest(String,Object)) to see the request that was being sent, and saw that it was sending a property called `payload` which was blank.

Changed `.resource` to  `.payload` and the request was successful.